# Casting from IEnumerable<Product> to IEnumerable<IProduct<object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that is of type `IEnumerable<Product>`

```
// var objEnum is of type IEnumerable<Product>
```

I have a function with parameter `IEnumerable<IProduct<object>>`

```
void MethodName (IEnumerable<IProduct<object>> obj) { return; }
```

I want to call the function:

```
MethodName( objEnum )
```

but it seems I need to cast objEnum to `IEnumerable<IProduct<object>>` somehow, am I right in needing to cast it? Is this possible? What methods can I apply to objEnum to make pass correctly?

If NotProduct is another type defined by

```
class NotProduct 
{
}
```

and IProduct is defined by

```
interface IProduct<T> 
{ 
    void IProductMethod(T obj);
}
```

my Product class is defined as follows:

```
class Product : IProduct<NotProduct>
{ 
    void IProductMethod(NotProduct obj) { return;}
}
```

I am using my method as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Product> productList = new List<Product>(); 
MethodName(productList);
// return nothing, do nothing, just don't throw an exception
```

EDIT: FULL CODE

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace ConsoleApp1

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");



            IEnumerable<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

            NotProduct notProduct = new NotProduct();

            MyMethods.MethodName(productList, notProduct);



            IEnumerable<AnotherProduct> anotherProductList = new List<AnotherProduct>();

            NotAnotherProduct notAnotherProduct = new NotAnotherProduct();

            MyMethods.MethodName(anotherProductList, notAnotherProduct);



            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Program ran sucessfully");

        }



    }



    public static class MyMethods

    {

        public static void MethodName(IEnumerable<IProduct<object>> collection, object obj)

        {

            foreach (IProduct<object> aProduct in collection)

            {

                if (obj is NotProduct && aProduct is IProduct<NotProduct>)

                {

                    aProduct.IProductMethod(obj);

                }

                else if (obj is NotAnotherProduct && aProduct is IProduct<NotAnotherProduct>)

                {

                    aProduct.IProductMethod(obj);

                }

            }

        }



    }



    public interface IProduct<T>

    {

        void IProductMethod(T t);

    }



    public class NotAnotherProduct

    {



    }



    public class AnotherProduct : IProduct<NotAnotherProduct>

    {

        public void IProductMethod(NotAnotherProduct t)

        {

            return;

        }

    }



    public class NotProduct

    {

    }



    public class Product : IProduct<NotProduct>

    {

        public void IProductMethod(NotProduct t)

        {

            return;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you get any issue while calling method that accepts IEnumerable<IProduct<object>> obj with objEnum

Comment: Why you mentioned NotProduct class? my understanding is you are trying to pass IEnumerable<Product>  object as parameter to a method that accepts IEnumerable<Product<object>>. Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @RamanathanGanesan That is incorrect. Although subtile, I am trying to pass IEnumerable<Product> to IEnumerable< **I** Product<object>>. I mention the NotProduct class because I want Product to implement the interface with a different generic type

Comment: @RamanathanGanesan 
Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Product>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IProduct<object>>'

Comment: FYI, method names should be `PascalCase` in C# (referring to `methodName`). And the `IProductMethod` has to be public in the `Product` class in order to fulfil the interface contract.

Comment: IProductMethod doesn't if it's only getting called external as a resource. I think your issue is: "void methodName (IEnumerable<IProduct<object>> obj) { return; } "... without seeing how your calling it, I couldn't say... but shouldn't the "object" be NotProduct

Comment: Not necessarily.  I want to be able make another class, call it NewProduct inherit IProduct<NotNewProduct>. Then pass IEnumerable<NewProduct> as IEnumerable<IProduct<object>> into **M**ethodName( ). It really doesn't matter what I'm doing in the function. It's more of like, how do I pass it correctly? I edited my comment to show how I am calling it.

Comment: It sound like you've over architected something.  Why you need a generic interface? for  `void IProductMethod(T obj);`  Why can't you just have `void IProductMethod(IAnotherInterface obj);`

Comment: I could add IAnotherInterface which I could use to cast to IEnumerable<IProduct<IAnotherInterface>> instead of IEnumerable<IProduct<object>>. But then I have to implement IAnotherInterface to the 25 'T' classes that IProduct implements! Is this what you meant by using IProductMethod(IAnotherInterface obj)